# useReducer - how to tell when state has been updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reducers

When using useReducer to manage state, the internal state update is deferred.

I.e. if I were to initialize a reducer with something like

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {prop: ""})
```

... then later call a dispatch like so ...

```
dispatch({
   type: 'ACTION_THAT_UPDATES_PROP'
});
console.log(state.prop)
```

... the value of "state.prop" wouldn't contain the new value, due to the deferred state update.

Is there a way to get the newly updated state? In other words, I'm looking for a similar mechanism provided by React's setState method, where you could do something like

```
this.setState({
   propName: "newPropValue"
}, () => {
   // state.propName would have value of "newPropValue" here
})
```

Comment: AFAIK, no, there is no useState mutator callback, it'll just be available on the next render cycle... I'm not sure why you'd want to use this value in the same cycle, but you could wrap your dispatch in an useEffect hook with the `state` value in its dependency array, or you could create a custom "useStateWithCallback" hook that takes a callback function in it's constructor that uses that new value, but this seems more like a code smell or hook anti-pattern. If you want to do stuff with the new state value then use `useEffect` to operate on the new `state.prop` value.

Comment: From source code https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L1131

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev - wow, thanks for finding that needle in a haystack for me. Upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it, but not in the body of the function nor directly after the dispatch, since the state needs to be updated first. React's state and lifecycle mandates that the new state won't be approachable in the context of the current state.

The way to do so is to use `useEffect`:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state.prop)
  }, [state.prop]);
```